# Need help to figure out network connections

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking

These are the pieces of my puzzle:

- A Raspberry PI (running volumio) connected to an amplifier and speakers.
- Router #1 connected to the internet and router #2 connected to the PI
- My music is in a usb hard disk connected to router #2 (the PI is not powerful enough to make it spin).
- An Alfa R36 and AWUS036H in their box (they may be helpful)

So if I want the PI to play music I connect to router #2 and if I want to go online I connect to router #1. This is very impractical, also because I cannot stream music to my speakers (volumio supports spotify, for example).

How can I have one single network that allows me to do both things?
An important restriction is that the two routers are far from each other and I cannot run an ethernet cable across my house.

EDIT:
I did some research before asking this: I found an article explaining how to do it using custom software and my router model is not supported.

Comment: There seems to be lack of research on your part. Try googling `connect two routers in one network`.

Comment: Hey, easy. I did google that, and I found an article showing how to do it using custom firmware, which for my D-Link model (DIR-636L) I cannot use because it's not supported, so I judged that solution a dead end.

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive, glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the easiest solution was to ditch router #2 and use the alfa antenna to connect the PI to router #1 with the hard drive attached to router #1 as well!

By the way, not the easiest thing to configure volumio to connect to router #1 while sshing from network #2!